# Insert calculated values into different DOM elements

Tags: javascript

I have a working formula that calculates PMT based on the interest rates, I see that it's working because the output in the console.log is correct. My question is, how can I take the results in the console.log and place each amount into it's own div?

For example, the first div is 4.125%, I want to display the dollar amount in the div right after it, then for the 3.125%, I want to display the dollar amount right after it and so on

Here is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/yecDj/19/

```
var p = 1000;
var thirtyYear = parseFloat(-Math.abs(360)); /*30 YR term in months*/

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var costPerThousand = "$" + (p * ((parseFloat(document.getElementById('rate' + i).innerHTML) / 100 / 12) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + (parseFloat(document.getElementById('rate' + i).innerHTML) / 100 / 12)), thirtyYear))))).toFixed(2);

    console.log(costPerThousand);
}
```

I'm looking to do this in javascript only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `console.log` with:

```
document.querySelector('#rate' + i).textContent = costPerThousand;
```

- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector)
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yecDj/21/)

Comment: OP was asking how to populate the adjacent divs. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yecDj/22

Comment: @isherwood Opps Updated!